# Can I fill my sous vide container completely full?

Tags: sous-vide

I am cooking a brisket in a 12l container right now. It is packed absolutely full right now. Water covers everything, but pieces are pressed against the sides and against each other. Is this ok?

Comment: If you have a packer brisket, have you split the point and the flat?

Comment: Yes. I separated the point from the flat already

Answer (score 14):

No, that doesn't sound good. The circulating water is what transfers heat efficiently to everything, making sure the water is the same temperature everywhere. If the flow is obstructed that can't happen. And if the food isn't all surrounded by water that's held at the desired temperature, it won't get heated as desired.

Comment: Yeah, at a minimum, it's going to take longer, and depending where it heats and measures from, you may have issues with uneven hearing. When I've somewhat overloaded mine, I've periodically moved the packages around to minimise the issues.